# Стилизация таблицы

Tags: css, css3, sass, css-selectors

Нужно сделать годовое расписание. События необходимо размещать прямо на расписании. Я уже кое-что набросал, но возникли некоторые вопросы.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

1. Можно ли добиться того, чтобы фоновый цвет ячеки залазил на границу? (Красная стрелка показывает) Сейчас я закрашиваю только саму ячейку. Граница своего цвета. Я хотел бы, чтобы ячейка была как бы сплошной, при этом border был виден на заднем фоне. Может, можно как-нибудь задать opacity border'y?
2. При наведении на фоновую область (событие), нужно, чтобы путь к этому событию подсвечивался (зеленый пунктир). Я задал особый стиль ячейкам, которые должны подстветиться, при наведении при на событие. Но задался вопросом, а как теперь написать селектор, который бы выбирал эти ячейки? С помощью селектора ~ я смог бы подстветить ячейки после моего события. Но мне ведь нужно подстветить до. Насколько я знаю, такого селектора в css нет, который бы позволил стилизовать предыдущие элементы. Можно ли как-нибудь решить эту задачу?

Answer (score 1):

Про `opacity` - есть цвета в формате rgba`(r,g,b,a)`, где `a` - задается прозрачность (как opacity для цвета). Если правильно понял про пути - без javascript не обойдетесь

```js
var table = $('#table');
table.on('mousemove', function(event) {
  if (event.target.tagName != 'TD') {
    return;
  } else {
    //Обнуляем стиль ячеек
    $('td').css({
      'background': 'inherit'
    })
    //Получаем элемент по которому кликнули
    var target = event.target;
    //Выбранный элемент "подсвечиваем" цветом
    $(target).css({
      'background': '#212121'
    })
    //Берем всех соседей выбранного элемента выше по дереву и подсвечиваем "путь"
    $(target).prevAll().css({
      'background': 'red'
    })
  }
})
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

th {
  background: lightblue;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>lorem</th>
      <th>lorem</th>
      <th>lorem</th>
      <th>lorem</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>lorem</td>
      <td>lorem</td>
      <td>lorem</td>
      <td>lorem</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>lorem</td>
      <td>lorem</td>
      <td>lorem</td>
      <td>lorem</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>lorem</td>
      <td>lorem</td>
      <td>lorem</td>
      <td>lorem</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Спасибо. Как по Вашему будет выглядеть более правильным решение с применением JavaScript?

Comment: @UladzislauRadzko, добавил пример реализации, Вы такое поведение задумывали?

Comment: @UladzislauRadzko, я сделал инлайновыми стилями выделение - можете вешать свои css классы на активную ячейку и на соседей

Comment: подобную логику я уже сообразил на css. Идея похожая: закрашиваем все ячейки красным, затем выбираем ячейку на которую пользователь наводит, красим ее в черный и, используя селектор ~, выбираем все следующие ячейки за выбранной и красим их в белый.

Но стал вопрос, как подстветить путь сверху.

Answer (score 0):

```css
table {
  background-color: red;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
   background-color: blue;
   border-right: 3px solid blue;
   border-top: 3px solid red;
   border-bottom: 3px solid red;
}

td:hover {
   border-bottom: 3px dotted white;
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
   <td>правая сторона рамки окрашена тем же цветом что и фон</td>
   <td> --> а это правая ячейка </td></tr>
</table>
```